# BIRT report running generates NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt, birt-deapi

I created simple app to generate pdf report using Eclipse BIRT. I loaded jars from `ReportEngine` folder into project build path. Code looks like this:

```
EngineConfig config;
try{
    config = new EngineConfig( );
    config.setEngineHome( "C:\\birt-runtime-2_6_2\\birt-runtime-2_6_2\\ReportEngine" );
    config.setLogConfig("c:/temp", Level.FINE);
    ReportEngine engine = new ReportEngine(config);
    engine.changeLogLevel( Level.WARNING );
    String name = "C:\\Users\\Djordje\\EclipseProjects\\ReportingApp\\new_report.rptdesign";
    IReportRunnable report = engine.openReportDesign(new FileInputStream(name  ));
    PDFRenderOption pdf = new PDFRenderOption();
    pdf.setOutputFormat("pdf");
    pdf.setOption(PDFRenderOption.PAGE_OVERFLOW, Integer.valueOf(PDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_TO_MULTIPLE_PAGES));
    pdf.setOption( IRenderOption.HTML_PAGINATION, Boolean.FALSE );
    pdf.setOutputFileName("D:/djole" +".pdf");
    IRunAndRenderTask task  = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(report);
    task.setRenderOption(pdf);
    task.run();
}catch ( Exception e1 ){
}
```

And here is the error I get when I run the project:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/IRenderOption
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRenderOption
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong, and is there any tutorial for developing code for running report on desktop app?

[image]
[image]
[image]
HERE IS ALL JARS LOADED INTO CLASSPATH
[image]

Comment: Could you add your classpath settings? So you have a different seting vor your runtime the for comoile time?

Comment: Im not sure I understood you.

Comment: How do you build the application? Maven, Ant? Eclipse itself? How do you run the application? Tomcat? Jboss? Please show your classpath (contained libraries) for running the app as well as compiling the app, there seems to be different settings for both of those.

Comment: The application is built in Eclipse, its just a test app with main method that is posted in question. I run application as a simple console app. The classpath is posted in question.

Comment: Hm, I guess the referenced birt_runtime Jar is just referenced, and you should put this jar into the Runtime Path of the application.

Comment: And, how I`m supposed to do that. I tried to change runtime classpath by setting %CLASSPATH% enviroment variable and by setting classpath in Edit launch configuration window. Is there any good tutorial on this? Thanks in advance, man!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using earlier version of birt_runtime, 4.4.1 to be specific. Thanks to triplem for all the effort.